# Socket de comunição em serviço Windows

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, node.js, socket

Seguinte, estou com problema com uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo, eu preciso realizar uma comunicação entre um serviço Windows e uma aplicação web, o serviço Windows vai ficar na maquina local(cliente) e eu preciso de algum modo realizar uma comunicação com esse serviço Windows e que de preferência o cliente da aplicação web fosse em java script!

Desde já agradeço!

OBS: Estou utilizando Razor + C# MVC6 e java script.

Comment: Esse "serviço" do windows, é nativo ou você que criou com c#?

Comment: Eu ainda não criei ele, mas está no escopo do projeto.  Ele não é nativo, ele será desenvolvido em c#.

Comment: Outra coisa, esse serviço será como se fosse um "servidor web" similar ao PHP? Se for apenas uma aplicação desktop há uma reposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299389/c-sharp-communication-with-browser-using-javascript) de como comunicar c# desktop com javascript. Se não for isso, basta criar urls a serem acessadas na sua aplicação web.

Comment: É apenas uma aplicação desktop que pretendo controlar ela por uma pagina web que vai ser aberta no navegador, porem ela vai estar hospedada em um servidor remoto por isso que precisava ser em Java Script, vou dar uma olhada no post que você deixou acima, obrigado Juven!